# Conjugacy classes in free groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory, free-groups, combinatorial-group-theory

Let $F = F_k$ be a free group of finite rank $k$. The length of a conjugacy class is defined to be the word-length of a shortest representative.

Given a number $n$, how many conjugacy classes of length $n$ are there?

A precise formula would be great, but even an asymptotic estimation would be enough (even only for $F_2$).

More generally, is there any reference that studies combinatorial properties of free groups and their conjugacy classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exponential. Indeed, a lower bound on the number of conjugacy classes of length $n$ in the free group of rank $k$ is:
$$2k(2k-1)^{n-2}(2k-2)/n.$$
Here, the $2k(2k-1)^{n-2}(2k-2)$ is the number of freely and cyclically reduced words of length $n$, whilst dividing by $n$ partitions these off into conjugacy classes. Its a lower bound because we don't always need to divide by $n$ (consider, for example, the word $a^n$). The exponential term $(2k-1)^{n-2}$ dominates as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

The key phrase you can google is "conjugacy growth function". From memory, this topic was first formalized and studied in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1003.1293) of Guba and Sapir, so you can look at the papers which cite it. [Conjugacy growth typically refers to the area of balls, and you care about the perimeter, but they are related.]